# sequelize model's .create() method seems to have gone missing

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

So I've got a small REST API built with express.js and sequelize that I've refactored out into several files, because I wanted to be but in the process the .create() method for my models seems to have 'disappeared'. (I'm new to JS btw)

```
// carrot.js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const carrotModel = {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4
    },
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
    },
    color_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 255
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
    }
};

module.exports = {
    carrotModel: carrotModel
}
==================================================
// db.js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const AssociateModel = require('./associate').associateModel;
const CarrotModel = require('./carrot').carrotModel;
const CategoryModel = require('./category').categoryModel;
const ColorModel = require('./color').colorModel;

let connObj = new Sequelize(
    'db', 
    'username', 
    'password', {
        host: 'localhost',
        dialect: 'sqlite',
        storage: 'tempstorage.db'
    }, {timestamps: false});

let associate = connObj.define('associate', AssociateModel);
let carrot = connObj.define('carrot', CarrotModel);
let color = connObj.define('color', ColorModel);

let category = connObj.define('category', CategoryModel);
category.hasOne(color, {as: 'foregroundColor'});
category.hasOne(color, {as: 'backgroundColor'});

connObj.sync().then(() => {
    console.log('all tables created');
})

module.exports = {
    Color: color,
    Category: category,
    Associate: associate,
    Carrot: carrot,
}
==================================================
// genericModelActions.js
module.exports = {
    getAll: (model) => {
        return model.findAll();
    },
    getSpecific: (model, data) => {
        return model.findById(req.params.modelId);
    },
    createModelInstance: (model, data) => {
        return model.create(...data);
    },
    updateModelInstance: (model, data) => {
        return model.update(...data, {where: {id: data.id}});
    },
    deleteModelInstance: (model, modelId) => {
        return model.destroy({where: {id: modelId}});
    }
}
==================================================
// carrotController.js
const generics = require('./genericModelActions');
const Carrot = require('../models/db').Carrot;

module.exports = {
    getAllCarrots: (req, res, next) => {
        generics
            .getAll(Carrot)
            .then(carrots => {
                res.send({results: carrots});
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.send({error: error});
            });
    },

    getSpecificCarrot: (req, res, next) => {
        generics
            .getSpecific(Carrot, req.params.carrotId)
            .then(carrots => {
                res.send({results: carrots});
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.send({error: error});
            });
    },

    createCarrot: (req, res, next) => {
        console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Carrot));
        console.log(Carrot.prototype);
        req.body.createdAt = +Date.now()
        req.body.updatedAt = +Date.now()
        generics
             .createModelInstance(Carrot, req.body)
             .then(carrots => {
                 res.send({results: carrots})
             });
    },

    updateCarrot: (req, res, next) => {
        req.body.updatedAt = +Date.now();
        generics.update(Carrot, req.body)
    },
    deleteCarrot: (req, res, next) => {
    }
}
==================================================
// carrotRoutes.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var controller = require('../controllers/carrotController');

router.get('/', controller.getAllCarrots);
// TODO: Change this to POST to accommodate more complex search queries.
router.get('/:carrotId', controller.getSpecificCarrot);
router.post('/', controller.createCarrot);
router.patch('/', controller.updateCarrot);
router.delete('/', controller.deleteCarrot);

module.exports = router;
==================================================
const express = require('express');

const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
const booksRouter = require('./routes/bookRoutes');
const categoriesRouter = require('./routes/categoryRoutes');
const carrotsRouter = require('./routes/carrotRoutes');

const sql = require('./models/db');

const app = express();

// view engine setup
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// custom model route setup
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/books', booksRouter);
app.use('/categories', categoriesRouter);
app.use('/carrots', carrotsRouter);

// sql.sync().then(() => {
//   app.listen(3000, () => {
//     console.log('basic app listening on 3000');
//   })
// });

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on 3000');
})
==================================================
// OUTPUT
output of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Carrot) (in carrotController.js) = 
   [ 'length',
  'prototype',
  'name',
  'sequelize',
  'options',
  'associations',
  'underscored',
  'tableName',
  '_schema',
  '_schemaDelimiter',
  'rawAttributes',
  'primaryKeys',
  '_timestampAttributes',
  '_readOnlyAttributes',
  '_hasReadOnlyAttributes',
  '_isReadOnlyAttribute',
  '_dataTypeChanges',
  '_dataTypeSanitizers',
  '_booleanAttributes',
  '_dateAttributes',
  '_hstoreAttributes',
  '_rangeAttributes',
  '_jsonAttributes',
  '_geometryAttributes',
  '_virtualAttributes',
  '_defaultValues',
  'fieldRawAttributesMap',
  'fieldAttributeMap',
  'uniqueKeys',
  '_hasBooleanAttributes',
  '_isBooleanAttribute',
  '_hasDateAttributes',
  '_isDateAttribute',
  '_hasHstoreAttributes',
  '_isHstoreAttribute',
  '_hasRangeAttributes',
  '_isRangeAttribute',
  '_hasJsonAttributes',
  '_isJsonAttribute',
  '_hasVirtualAttributes',
  '_isVirtualAttribute',
  '_hasGeometryAttributes',
  '_isGeometryAttribute',
  '_hasDefaultValues',
  'attributes',
  'tableAttributes',
  'primaryKeyAttributes',
  'primaryKeyAttribute',
  'primaryKeyField',
  '_hasPrimaryKeys',
  '_isPrimaryKey',
  'autoIncrementAttribute',
  '_scope',
  '_scopeNames' ]

Output of console.log(Carrot.prototype) (located in carrotController.js) = 
carrot {
  _customGetters: {},
  _customSetters: {},
  validators: {},
  _hasCustomGetters: 0,
  _hasCustomSetters: 0,
  rawAttributes: 
   { id: 
      { type: UUID {},
        primaryKey: true,
        defaultValue: UUIDV4 {},
        Model: carrot,
        fieldName: 'id',
        _modelAttribute: true,
        field: 'id' },
     name: 
      { type: [Object],
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        Model: carrot,
        fieldName: 'name',
        _modelAttribute: true,
        field: 'name' },
     color_id: 
      { type: [Object],
        defaultValue: 255,
        Model: carrot,
        fieldName: 'color_id',
        _modelAttribute: true,
        field: 'color_id' },
     createdAt: 
      { type: [Object],
        allowNull: false,
        Model: carrot,
        fieldName: 'createdAt',
        _modelAttribute: true,
        field: 'createdAt' },
     updatedAt: 
      { type: [Object],
        allowNull: false,
        Model: carrot,
        fieldName: 'updatedAt',
        _modelAttribute: true,
        field: 'updatedAt' } },
  attributes: [ 'id', 'name', 'color_id', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt' ],
  _isAttribute: { [Function: memoized] cache: MapCache { size: 0, __data__: [Object] } } }

CONSOLE OUTPUT:
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at createCarrot (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/controllers/carrotController.js:32:16)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15
    at next (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)
    at Function.handle (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/myhomedir/Projects/market-rewrite/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
```

Sending a POST request to the relevant route calls the controller as expected, but the whole thing fails with an `undefined is not a function` error.

I can't, for the life of me, figure out what exactly is wrong here. Both console.log() and Chrome's inspector verify that a model is indeed being passed in but it seems that the .create(). .build() and .save() don't seem to be there either. Clearly I've missed something important, because I can't see anything wrong with my code.

The whole thing works when I shove everything into a single file, but who wants to do that?

```
Using:
Node.js v8.10.0
Express 4.16.3
Sequelize 4.37.5
```

Folder structure:

```
├── app.js
├── controllers
│   ├── associateController.js
│   ├── bookController.js
│   ├── carrotController.js
│   ├── categoryController.js
│   ├── colorController.js
│   └── genericModelActions.js
├── isolatedSequelizeTest.js
├── models
│   ├── associate.js
│   ├── book.js
│   ├── carrot.js
│   ├── category.js
│   ├── color.js
│   └── db.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── public
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── bookRoutes.js
│   ├── carrotRoutes.js
│   ├── categoryRoutes.js
│   └── users.js
├── spec
│   ├── carrotRoutes.spec.js
│   └── support
│       └── jasmine.json
└── tempstorage.db
```

Comment: Will you please also post the folder structure?

Comment: @VivekDoshi I posted the file structure, as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to change is :

```
return model.create(...data);
```

To

```
return model.create(data);
// OR
return model.create({...data});
```

Comment: That did it.This error has been hounding me for days now, so I appreciate the help.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @cornjuliox , It happens some time :) , Glad to know that it helped , Happy Coding BTW :D